# can't multiprocess user defined code - cannot pickle

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pickle

I tried using multiprocessing on my task, which generally means to do some calculation and then pass back the result. The problem is that the code defining the calculation is defined by user, it is compiled from string before the execution. This works perfect using `exec()`, `eval()` or `compile()` etc. when being run in the main process. The example below works only for `f1` function but not for `f2`. I get 'Can't pickle class 'code'`. Is there any way round this? For example using multiprocessing differently? Or using other package? Or some more low level stuff? Unfortunatelly passing the string to the process and then compiling inside the process is not an option for me because of the design of the whole application (i.e. the code string is 'lost' and only the compiled version is available).

```
import multiprocessing

def callf(f, a):
    exec(f, {'a': a})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    f = compile("print(a)", filename="<string>", mode="exec")
    callf(f, 10)  # this works
    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=callf, args=(f, 20))  # this does not work
    process.start()
    process.join()
```

UPDATE: here is another attempt, which is actually closer to my actual need. It results in different error message, but also cannot pickle the function.

```
import multiprocessing

if __name__ == "__main__":
    source = "def f(): print('done')"
    locals = dict()
    exec(source, {}, locals)
    f = locals['f']
    f()  # this works
    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=f)  # this does not work
    process.start()
    process.join()
```

Comment: You can't pickle the compiled object `f`. So that means you can't really pass it to your process. Could you `compile` each code block with a unique filename (i.e. save as a file instead), and then just pass the filename to each sub-process?

Comment: Sorry, just re-reading the docs for `compile`, seems I misread things. Not sure if you can save the compiled code to a file that easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pickle` can't serialize code objects but [dill](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dill/0.2.5) can. There is a dill-based fork of multiprocessing called [multiprocessing_on_dill](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/multiprocessing_on_dill) but I have no idea how good it is. You could also just dill-encode the code object to make standard multiprocessing happy.

```
import multiprocessing
import dill

def callf_dilled(f_dilled, a):
    return callf(dill.loads(f_dilled), a)

def callf(f, a):
    exec(f, {'a': a})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    f = compile("print(a)", filename="<string>", mode="exec")
    callf(f, 10)  # this works
    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=callf_dilled, 
        args=(dill.dumps(f), 20))  # now this works too!
    process.start()
    process.join()
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to `dill`, `pathos` and related stuff which replaces the broken `pickle`. There is a part of `pathos`, called `multiprocess` which is a fork of `multiprocessing`. Installing this package and mere replacing of `multiprocessing` with `multiprocess` did the work for me.